# having trouble passing a prop in React using a component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, state, react-props

I am trying to pass a prop and generate a simple paragraph. I am following the docs but I am not sure what I am doing wrong. I am sure the solution is utterly simple but I am just not finding it. I take an input and generate a paragraph with that dog's name. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

class DisplayName extends React.Component{
  render() {
    return (
        <p>
          <span>{this.props.value}</span>
        </p>
      )
  }
}

class NameForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      value: ''
    };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this)

  }

  handleChange(event){
    this.setState({
      value: event.target.value
    })
  }

  handleSubmit(event){
    event.preventDefault()
    return(
      <DisplayName
        value={this.state.value}
      />
    )
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <label>
            Favorite Dog Names:
            <input type="text" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange} />
          </label>
          <input type='submit' value='Submit'></input>
        </form>
        <div>
         {this.handleSubmit}
        </div>
      </div>

    )
  }

}

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <NameForm />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using `this.handleSubmit` in two different contexts: one to handle a click event, the second to render an element. This should be two separate functions since they are unrelated.

The code in the `handleSubmit` function:

```js
handleSubmit(event){
  event.preventDefault()
  return(
    <DisplayName
      value={this.state.value}
    />
  )
}
```

should become:

```js
handleSubmit(event){
  event.preventDefault()
  // shouldn't be returning a component
}
```

then, in render, this:

```js
<div>
  {this.handleSubmit}
</div>
```

should become:

```js
<div>
  <DisplayName value={this.state.value} />
</div>
```

Comment: Totally makes sense! I see now. My only issue is that the name I type just shows up as I type it, not on submit. I guess that I was trying to do with using the ```handleSubmit``` to have it activate only on submit. Could you point me in the right direction on how to have the name display upon submit?

Comment: In the `handleSubmit` method, you could set a state value (eg: `this.setState({ submitted })`, or use a hook) and then in your render method replace it with `{this.state.submitted && <DisplayName value={this.state.value} />}` and it should only render once submitted.